# Password attempt limit

Tags: c++, loops

a c++ newbie here.

How do I limit the amount of times one can attempt to enter a password in this programme? So far, it reprints until the correct password is entered. I'd like to set a limit of 3 attempts and execute a 'attempt limit reached' or something of the sort.

```
{

string password;

while (true)
{
    cout << "Please enter your password.\n";
    cin >> password;
    if (password == "password")
    {
        cout << "Welcome!\n";
        break;
    }
   cout << "Please try again.\n";
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Jess.

Comment: Add a counter and check for it to break the loop.

Comment: A quick way would be to define `int c = 3;` and `while(c--)`, which will exit when c becomes 0.

Comment: You might also want to introduce a timeout between attempts.

Comment: Also, one thing to keep in mind for the future: a real-world program wouldn't (or at least shouldn’t) store passwords in plain text.  They’d store a hash of the password and compare `hashf(input) == password_hash`. Often, they salt the passwords, too, getting something like `hashf(input+salt) == password_hash`.

Comment: Also randomize the time before responding. A lot of really useful information can be gained from how fast a system replies... unless the system lies.

Comment: I probably should have clarified, this is purely an exercise to practice loops lol. Some of the stuff above is a little more advanced at the moment for where I'm at. Thanks for the info though :) Will certainly come in handy further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
string password;

//Ask for a password as long as the user hasn't incorrectly entered one three or more times
for (int tries = 0; tries < 3; ++tries)
{
    cout << "Please enter your password.\n";
    cin >> password;
    if (password == "password")
    {
        cout << "Welcome!\n";
        break;
    }
    cout << "Please try again.\n";
}

//If the password limit was reached without a correct password, send them an error message
if (password != "password") cout << "Sorry, try again later.\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have done the trick! Although the 'if' code at the end there didn't execute the error message. The 'for' loop achieved what I was adter though, Thanks!

Comment: No problem! It's odd that the message doesn't print, though. It should, seeing as the 3 incorrect passwords fulfills the criteria of the `if` statement.

Comment: It works for me on Windows 7 x86 with C++11 on Code::Blocks 13.12